# Android InputType for IP address programatically

Tags: android, keyboard, numbers

I need a keyboard that allows the user to input an IP Address, so I only want to allow numbers and multiple decimal points. To make it clear, I am not interested in validating with a full keyboard to see if the input values are correct, I want the keyboard itself to be limited. I know how to do this in XML as shown below:

```
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    android:digits="0123456789."
```

That works like a charm!

But now I need to do the same with an EditText in the code behind. After looking for quite some time the most common answers revolve around this:

```
    EditText text = new EditText(this);
    text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
    text.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789."));
```

Obviously the reason I am asking this question is because that doesn't work. I simply get a number keyboard with no decimal point.

There has to be a way, any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Better you can check after the input if anything wrong then just show an error message..

Comment: possible duplicate of [IP address textbox in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882918/ip-address-textbox-in-android)

Comment: I don't agree there, the question asks for validation and most of the answers are specified towards that. I am not interested in that. I want a limited keyboard from the start.

Answer (score 1):

You need one more listener:

```
 text.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false,false));
```

Here is the code that allows you to display a soft keyboard with only numbers and a dot (but allows you to enter multiple dots).

```
EditText text = new EditText(this);

text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
text.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789."));
text.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false,false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? this should solve your problem.

```
text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

the code you have written will only set the last inputtype you have set. constants are binary values, thus if you want to set multiple input type , then you need to `|` it. This is the same rule if you did in xml.

Comment: Afraid not bud, if I use this it only allows one decimal point.